# IIS ignore persian character in url django project

Tags: django, iis

I have developed a Django app on IIS that has some Persian URLs parts. The Problem is that the application completely ignore Persian parts.

i config .NET Globalization like this:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BM3Yf.png)
but the urls ignored
When I run the project locally on the server, the URLs work

Comment: RFC2396 states that you cannot use any non-alphanumeric characters. You can encode them, but such URLs are not very readable/SEO friendly. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/984236/iis-ignore-persian-text-in-urls-with-django